# How do i remove trailing special characters from NSString in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I remove trailing special characters from NSString in Objective C?

> Example
>
> > http://www.stackoverflow.com/// -> http://www.stackoverflow.com 
> >     http://www.stackoverflow.com. -> http://www.stackoverflow.com 
> >     http://www.stackoverflow.com... -> http://www.stackoverflow.com

**(Update)**

By special characters, I mean anything not in the alphabet and not a number.

Comment: define "special characters". also try regular expression

Comment: special char = anything not in the alphabet and not a number

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

-jwz, 1997

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming it's safe to remove those special characters from the beginning of the string as well, you could use -stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:

```
NSCharacterSet *special = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:special];
```

Comment: i think this should suffice for my requirements. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a regular expression:

```
NSString *result = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^A-Za-z0-9]*$"
                                                     withString:@""
                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it in regular expression. you can tweak what character to trim by change `regex`

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *string = // your string
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
```